# jQuery Tokeninput Error in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to use jQuery Tokeninput as shown in Railscast #258 (revised). When I enter something in the tokeninput field, the field does not dropdown with results and I get the following javascript error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined`.

My json data works fine when I do a manual query on it, and the server request looks fine. I am trying to search the content column in my issues table, so I set propertyToSearch to "content".

Here is my code:

coffeescript:

```
jQuery ->
$('#fact_issue_tokens').tokenInput "/issues.json"
    theme: 'facebook'
    zindex: 11001
    propertyToSearch: 'content'
    tokenValue: 'content'
    hintText: 'Enter an issue'
    preventDuplicates: true
```

Issue Model:

```
def self.tokens(query)
  issues = where("content like ?", "%#{query}%")
  if issues.empty?
    [{id: "<<<#{query}>>>", content: "New: \"#{query}\""}]
  else
    issues
  end
end

def self.ids_from_tokens(tokens)
  tokens.gsub!(/<<<(.+?)>>>/) { create!(content: $1).id }
  tokens.split(',')
end
```

Issues Controller:

```
def index
  @issues = Issue.order(:content)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json: @issues.tokens(params[:q]) }
  end
end
```

Form:

```
<%= form_for(Fact.new, :url => kase_facts_path(current_kase), :html => {:class => "form-   
inline"}) do |f| %>

  <%= f.text_field :page, placeholder: 'Page' %>
  <%= f.text_field :description, placeholder: 'Description' %>

  <%= f.label :issue_tokens, 'Issue tags' %>
  <%= f.text_field :issue_tokens %>

  <%= f.hidden_field :source_id, :value => @source.id %>

  <%= f.submit 'Add Fact' %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Scott you try this

```
jQuery ->
  $('#fact_issue_tokens').tokenInput '/issues.json'
    theme: 'facebook'
    tokenLimit: 5
    minChars: 4
    preventDuplicates: true
    searchingText: "Enter an issue..."
    prePopulate: $('#fact_issue_tokens').data('load')
```

and think on your index because you are using (:content) not name might be your problem. I am bot sure why but i used title and i had a problem, i thought it was mysql or something. 
When you visit

```
http://localhost:3000/issues.json
```

Do you get the JSON data?

**Edit.**

Can you please try this for your form?

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :issue_tokens, "Issues" %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :issue_tokens, data: {load: @fact.issues} %>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I can get the JSON data from `http://localhost:3000/issues.json` I know that changing :name causes issues, but I specified 'propertyToSearch: 'content'' I thought that would change the search from :name to :content.

Comment: I changed my column name to "name", but I'm still having the same issue.

Comment: You did add the jquery.tokeninput.js and //= require jquery.tokeninput in the application.js ? Sorry to ask so many questions but i am wondering why it's causing you this error. Omhhh how does your form look like?

Comment: Yes, both js and css files are working. I'll add the form to my original post.

Comment: @Vezu : Hi Vezu and Scott, I am currently facing a strange problem with token-input. There are 2 text_fields in my view, but I can't figure out where did the duplicate come from?